# How to assign a JS method to a C# event in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, events, cefsharp

Suppose there is such a event in C#

```cs
public class Example {
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
}
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs { }
```

And `MyEvent` is raised in somewhere in C#.

How to assign a JS method that will be called when `MyEvent` is raised?

```js
MyExampleObj.MyEvent += function(sender, e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, unfortunately not currently supported.

Comment: I should clarify,  there's no out of the box support,  you can add your own without too much trouble. You can use a IJavascriptCallback to with a method on your c# object that gets called ever time you register an event handler,  passing in a function that references the JavaScript event handler. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Advanced-Async-JavaScript-Binding-(JSB)#javascript-callback As JavaScript events are somewhat limited to DOM elements you'd need to add your own addEventListener implementation, which should be pretty trivial. The JavaScript syntax above is invalid.

Comment: If you just need a register a single function per event then you could just add a addEventListener method to your bound class and call it directly from JavaScript.